# python ast vs json for str to dict translation

Tags: python, json, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a piece of code that receives a string formatted as a python dictionary

```
"{'a':'1','b':'2',...}"
```

which I need to convert to a proper dictionary.

I have tried two approaches, using `json.loads(s)` and `ast.literal_eval(s)`
ast seems to be much more robust, accepting any form of quotes in the string and "just works" while json seems to be very picky about the quoting specifics and wouldn't fail on only a single form of quote format. I really would like to be as flexible as possible with the input and thus prefer to use `ast`, however, some of my colleagues claim it might not be a "safe" module and function to use.

Can anyone advise on ast and ast.literal_eval() safety, especially compared to json.loads() ?

thanks

Comment: Is the quoting really like in your question? The single quotes don't match.

Comment: you're right, lemme fix that...

Comment: Only use `json.loads` if the data source is JSON. If it is just a `repr(python_dict)`, then even if sometimes it will work, it is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` - it's designed to do what you want. JSON happens to work as the syntax matches, but that isn't something you should rely on.

As to safety, `literal_eval()` is specifically designed to be safe to use on data from untrusted sources. The first word of [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), in fact, is 'Safely':

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the
>   values oneself.

Those that advised you against using it were probably thinking of `eval()`, which is indeed unsafe.

Comment: perfect, thanks. I'll wait for a few more replies, and set the answer