# can't read json file with python. getting type error: json object is 'TextIOWrapper'

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to read from a json file.

This is how I created the file:

```
import requests
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint

BASE_URL = "https://www.wikiart.org/en/api/2/UpdatedArtists"
artist_json_data = requests.get(BASE_URL).json()

with open('artistdata.json', 'w') as outfile:
    while artist_json_data['hasMore']:
        print(artist_json_data['paginationToken'])
        url = BASE_URL + "?paginationToken=" +artist_json_data['paginationToken']
        artist_json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        json.dump(artist_json_data, outfile, indent=4)
        time.sleep(1)
```

This is the beginning of my output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "57726da5edc2cb3880b4ca54",
            "artistName": "Paul Feeley",
            "url": "paul-feeley",
            "lastNameFirst": "Feeley Paul",
            "birthDay": "/Date(-1893456000000)/",
            "deathDay": "/Date(-126230400000)/",
```

When I try to read the same file with following code:

```
from pprint import pprint

with open('artistdata.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:    
    data = json.loads(data_file)
    pprint(data)
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

which I don't understand, because I can open the file in sublime as usual. How can I handle this?

### **Solved the issue with following code:**

the issue was that I mixed dumps and load. Now I am using dump and load

```
class Wikiart:
    '''Class to access wikiart.org Data'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.BASE_URL = "https://www.wikiart.org/en/"
        self.BASE_URL_API = self.BASE_URL + "api/2/"
        self.BASE_URL_MOVEMENT = self.BASE_URL + 'artists-by-art-movement/'
        self.ARTIST_DATA_URL = self.BASE_URL_API + "UpdatedArtists"

    def write_artist_data_into_json_file(self):
            artists = requests.get(ARTIST_DATA_URL).json()
            all_artists = artists['data']

            with open('artistdata.json', 'w') as outfile:
                while artists['hasMore']:
                    print('fetching next: pagination token',artists['paginationToken'])
                    url = BASE_URL + "?paginationToken=" + artists['paginationToken']
                    artists_next_page = requests.get(url).json()
                    next_artists = artists_next_page['data']
                    time.sleep(0.25)
                    all_artists = all_artists + next_artists
                    artists = artists_next_page
                json.dump(all_artists, outfile, indent=4)

from pprint import pprint

with open('artistdata.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`json.load()` is for loading a file. `json.loads()` works with strings.

Comment: `json.load()` gives me an error too `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1960 column 2 (char 94439)`

Comment: obviously I am mixing up things. let me dig into that

Answer (score 5):

3 ways to load a json file:

```
import json
import ast
with open(file_path) as file:
    data1 = json.load(file)
    data2 = json.loads(file.read())  
    data3 = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
```

You [should use json.load whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403744/why-should-json-loads-be-preferred-to-ast-literal-eval-for-parsing-json), but sometimes the JSON file is not strictly in the correct format (e.g. single quotes instead of double quotes). A solution is to use *ast.literal_eval()*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.load()` (without 's') instead of `json.loads()`

PS You will be using `json.load()` when loading from file. And `json.loads()` when working with string :)