# Reading file that contains multiple JSON objects (python)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have created a JSON file from my Google search API results.  I'm trying to read the file and parse the objects.

Each search result is one JSON array, which is shown below.  I have 200 of these arrays in a single JSON file.

```
{
  "kind": "customsearch#result",
  "title": "text here",
  "htmlTitle": "text here",
  "link": "link here",
  "displayLink": "text here",
  "snippet": "text here",
  "htmlSnippet": "text here",
  "cacheId": "ID string",
  "formattedUrl": "text here",
  "htmlFormattedUrl": "link here",
  "pagemap": {
  "metatags": [
    {
      "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    }
  ],
  "Breadcrumb": [
    {
      "title": "text here",
      "url": "link here",
    },
    {
      "title": "text here",
      "url": "link here",
    },
    {
      "title": "text here",
      "url": "link here",
    },
    {
      "title": "text here",
      "url": "link here",
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm having an issue reading the JSON file into json.load(s).

How do I read this file and start parsing the items?

```
def ingest_json(input):
try:
    with open(input, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        json_data = json.loads(f)
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    sys.exit(1)
```

throws this error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, 
bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

---

```
def ingest_json(input):
try:
    with open(input, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    sys.exit(1)
```

throws this error:

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
                   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 269 
                   column 2 (char 10330)
```

Comment: first code: use `load` instead `loads`

Comment: your json is not valid, use https://jsonlint.com/ to verify that your json is correct, for example: `"url": "link here",}`that comma is not correct, remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035799/cant-read-json-file-with-python-getting-type-error-json-object-is-textiowrap

Answer (score 3):

In `json.loads()`, the 's' stands for string so it only works on the string type.

`json.load()` is definitely the method you want, although it is very particular about the json being well formatted, and according to the specification a single JSON file can only contain a single JSON object.

Try splitting the data into multiple files, each with a single object, or split the string by object in your python before parsing. Also, check out [Can json.loads ignore trailing commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705304/can-json-loads-ignore-trailing-commas) for handling the trailing commas problem.