# Correct way of loading JSON from file into a Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am currently doing this to save JSON to a file:

```
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

and I am doing this to load JSON from a file into a Python dictionary:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
     data = json.loads(json.load(f))
```

I understand that `json.load` loads JSON from a file and `json.loads` loads JSON from a string.

When I call `json.load(f)` to load the JSON from file I get a string representation of the JSON object:

```
'{"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3}'
```

I then call `json.loads(json.load(f))` to convert that string representation to a Python dictionary:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

I understand that I can also use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert the string into a Python dictionary.

My question is - what is the correct way of loading JSON from a file directory into a Python dictionary? is it really necessary to call both `json.loads` and `json.load` to get JSON from a file into a dictionary?

Comment: I would certainly recommend using the `json` library as you did rather than `ast.literal_eval`, the former was made for exactly this purpose.

Comment: [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) should be returning objects, not a string. What's with the extra call to `.loads`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `data` must have already been a JSON string to begin with and then you double-encoded it during
the `json.dump`. Then of course you need to double-decode it later. So instead of encoding the original JSON with JSON again, just write it to the file as-is:

```
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't know if this is the definite *correct* way, but it works for me:

```
jd0 = {
   'foo': 1337,
   'bar': 'baz'
}
# Dump it somewhere
with open('/Dump/it/somewhere/test.json', 'w') as fh: 
    json.dump(jd0, fh)
```

If I then load it, its a dict again:

```
with open('/Dump/it/somewhere/test.json', 'r') as fh:
    jd1 = json.load(fh)
    print type(jd1) == dict
```

Prints

```
 True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current method is correct here. For `json.loads()` and `ast.literal_eval()`, they are parsing entirely different languages. If your json file is exactly the content you pasted here, I recommend using the json library as it's faster.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21223411/456105