# Open heavy string-text dictionaries in python

Tags: json, string, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I try to convert an heavy .txt which is the string of a dicionary like (a part):

```
"{'A45171': {'Gen_n': 'Putative uncharacterized protein', 'Srce': 'UniProtKB', 'Ref': 'GO_REF:0000033', 'Tax': 'NCBITaxon:684364', 'Gen_bl': 'BATDEDRAFT_15336', 'Gen_id': 'UniProtKB:F4NTD6', 'Ev_n': 'IBA', 'GO_n': 'ergosterol biosynthetic process', 'GO': 'GO:0006696', 'Org': 'Batrachochytrium dendrobatidis JAM81', 'Type': 'protein', 'Ev_e': 'ECO:0000318', 'Con': 'GO_Central'}, 'A43886': {'Gen_n': 'Uncharacterized protein', 'Srce': 'UniProtKB', 'Ref': 'GO_REF:0000002', 'Tax': 'NCBITaxon:9823', 'Gen_bl': 'RDH8', 'Gen_id': 'UniProtKB:F1S3H8', 'Ev_n': 'IEA', 'GO_n': 'estrogen biosynthetic process', 'GO': 'GO:0006703', 'Org': 'Sus scrofa', 'Type': 'protein', 'Ev_e': 'ECO:0000501', 'Con': 'InterPro'}}"
```

I've tryed `ast` module:

```
import ast
dic_gene_definitions = open("Gene_Ontology/output_data/dic_gene_definitions.txt", "r")
dic_gene_definitions = dic_gene_definitions.read()
dic_gene_definitions = ast.literal_eval(dic_gene_definitions)
```

Which weight 22Mb and when don't crush, it runs so slow.

I really wants to open an 500 Mb files... 
I'[ve look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval) `json` module which can open so faster, but in heavy dictionary string it crash also (not with short examples).

Any solution...?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What are the use cases you need a 500 Mb file loaded into memory for?

Comment: For a dictionary of protein annotations, which includes aminoacid secuences (aprox 300 bit for secuence + description, 66000 proteins).

Comment: Again, how will you use the dictionary... just to create the AST? I'm not a python guru by any means but would it make sense to create a hash list of keys that point to file offsets for the values and load that into memory first and, then, you could fault in the actual data value(s) when a key is referenced?

Comment: I don't understand much. I only takes an dictionary file from a string of a dictionary. I wants to save the data with a different key's inputs like an normal dictionary.  But I takes the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've look some non-RAM memory consuming method.

By use in Ubuntu's terminal:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

we can appreciate the RAM memory consumed by different opperations:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        2097148 19876   -1
```

By to operate with this example file (500Mb) by make an dictionary, for example,  best way is to open it from normal text tabulated data format, and  operate with minour RAM consumption:

```
with open("Gene_Ontology/output_data/GO_annotations_dictionary.txt", "r") as handle:
    for record in handle.read().splitlines():
        anote = record.split("\t")
```

`ast` module is fine but not by large files.