# Convert string representation of list into list

Tags: python, string, list

```
list_string = "[1,3,4,6]"
```

I tried `list_string[1:-1]` but it is giving `1,3,4,6`.
I also tried `list_string.split(',')` but again the brackets will be appended to first and last element i.e `'[1' , '3' , '4' , '6]'`

I can iterate over all the items and remove brackets from 1st and last element.
But what is the best and simple way to do this?

Comment: Is this JSON perhaps? Then use `json.loads()`. It'll depend on other factors however if it can be treated as JSON; if there are non-numeric values for example, such as `null` or `false` or `true` or strings.

Comment: In other words: please provide some more context as to where this data comes from. If you used `str()` or `repr()` on Python objects, you could use `ast.literal_eval()`, but perhaps you should try to avoid doing that first step in the first place.

Comment: if it's not JSON, you could combine your approaches - `list_string[1:-1].split(',')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your string is a simple list/dict/combination of lists and dicts, you can use one of the two packages mentioned below, listed in order of preference.

#### `json`

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[1, 2, 3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

This is definitely the preferred method if you are parsing raw json strings.

---

### `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

`ast.literal_eval` will safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None, bytes and sets.

Also [`json.loads` is significantly faster than `ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval). Use this ONLY IF you cannot use the `json` module first.

---

#### `yaml`

In some cases, you can also use the pyYAML library (you'll need to use PyPi to install it first).

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.safe_load('[1, 2, 3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Please do elaborate on when to use which one. `ast.literal_eval()` is slower, and there are *huge* differences between the two approaches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just know that the json is optimized to parse JSON strings, whereas literal_eval uses something like a parse tree to evaluate strings. Am I right? Will link to the docs.

Comment: JSON syntax differs materially from Python syntax. That JSON and Python syntax are the same *for this one example* is luck, not design.

Comment: The two functions then will act entirely differently when the input consists of something more complex than a list of numbers. The OP hasn't given us anything to go by, but future visitors stumbling upon this question may be tempted to try one or the other method *and not notice that they broke something* when their output consists of, say, strings with unicode escape sequences.