# How can i convert a string to a list?

Tags: python

I have a string such as `thislist = "[3, 2, 1]"` or `"[1]"`

**I need to convert it to a list with float (or int) elements**, but i don't know how to do it?

What i tried is this:

```
thislist = list(thislist)
```

But, when i try this solution, it gives me:

```
 ['[', '3', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '1', ']']
```

which is ***not*** what i need. Of course, i can do some more process to obtain my favorite result which is
`[3,2,1]`. But, i am looking for the most efficient approach!

Comment: More accurate dup (list of ints): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672561/convert-string-representation-of-list-into-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
thislist = "[3, 2, 1]"
goodList = json.loads(thislist) # this will give you [3, 2, 1]
```