# Is it possible to use ijson to create and load JSON objects in memory (not from/to a file)?

Tags: python, ijson

I'm trying to use `ijson` instead of `json` to be able to efficiently dump/load dictionaries to/from strings (in-memory, not from a file) [1].

Are there any examples for `ijson` analogous to standard dumping/loading with `json`? All sources I've seen that use `ijson` have examples with files only.

[1] -- Dictionaries are being converted to strings in order to store them in a set

Answer (score 3):

To complement omri_saadon's answer in the vein of performance,

Here is a link ([serializer speed comparisons](http://justinfx.com/2012/07/25/python-2-7-3-serializer-speed-comparisons/)) that measures some lesser known JSON modules, one of which was found to effectively outperform the others (`msgpack`) and can be used interchangeably with `json`.

Hence, instead of `ijson` or standard `json`, `msgpack` is presently being used for the dict/str conversions.

To install:
    `pip install msgpack`

To use:
    `import msgpack as json` `# can use dumps/loads functions`

Comment: As of [`msgpack-python == 0.5.0`](https://pypi.org/project/msgpack-python/0.5.0/) has been renamed to [`msgpack`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack/0.5.1), and deprecated as of [`msgpack-python == 0.5.1`](https://pypi.org/project/msgpack-python/0.5.1/).

Comment: An additional benchmark: http://lpetr.org/blog/archives/faster-json-parsing-python-ijson

Answer (score 1):

You can reach both goals (dict to string and string to dict without using the json lib).

Let's look at the above example:

```
import ast
di = {"a":2, "b": 3}

print (str(di))
>>> "{'a': 2, 'b': 3}"

print (type(str(di)))
>>> <class 'str'>

print (ast.literal_eval(str(di)))
>>> {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

print (type(ast.literal_eval(str(di))))
>>> <class 'dict'>
```

You have a dictionary, In order to turn it into string, you just need to cast it into `str`.

If you want to return the str to dict you can use the `ast` lib.

You can read more about [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display.

**EDIT:**

After further investigation and following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval) It seems that using json would get you to a faster results (performance).

Look at abarnert answer at the attached link, specifacally on:

> Why is json.loads so much faster ?
>
> Because Python literal syntax is a
>   more complex and powerful language than JSON, it's likely to be slower
>   to parse. And, probably more importantly, because Python literal
>   syntax is not intended to be used as a data interchange format (in
>   fact, it's specifically not supposed to be used for that), nobody is
>   likely to put much effort into making it fast for data interchange.

```
import json
di = {"a":2, "b": 3}

print (json.dumps(di))
>>> '{"a": 2, "b": 3}'

print (type(json.dumps(di)))
>>> <class 'str'>

print (json.loads(json.dumps(di)))
>>> {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

print (type(json.loads(json.dumps(di))))
>>> <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: I was previously considering eval, but I noticed that it was associated with poor performance. The reason I thought ijson would be a good approach is due to its efficiency. However, it's efficient relative to standard json so I don't know how it compares to eval.

Comment: read this [stackoverflow answer - Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) in order to get more idea.

Comment: I could be more clear. By efficiency, I mean speed. Let me know if you have any thoughts on what would be the most speed-efficient method of dict/str conversion.

Comment: @Phillip , Read this [answer - Why is json.loads an order of magnitude faster than ast.literal_eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval) in order to understand why using json is much faster than literal_eval

Comment: @Phillip , I've added an EDIT section to my answer, still all is in-memory. Good luck !