# convert a text list into list on python

Tags: python, list

I'm reading lists that have lost their format while conversions, so the orinial list looks now like:

```
my_list = '[[-0.2226099967956543, 0.2235500067472458, -0.2384900003671646, 0.14377999305725098]]'
```

for that I'm doing the following:

```
my_list = my_list.replace('[','').replace('[','').split()
type(my_list)
list
```

Which works, but doesn't looks very pythonic to me. Is thera better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json.loads`, also, I added an extra bracket at the end of `my_list` since it's missing a bracket:

```
>>> import json
>>> my_list = '[[-0.2226099967956543, 0.2235500067472458, -0.2384900003671646, 0.14377999305725098]]'
>>> json.loads(my_list)
[[-0.2226099967956543, 0.2235500067472458, -0.2384900003671646, 0.14377999305725098]]
>>> type(json.loads(my_list))
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

Comment: Note the string list in question has an (intentional?) bracket missing.

Comment: @TrebledJ I added one...

Answer (score 2):

So we have `ast`

```
my_list = '[-0.2226099967956543, 0.2235500067472458, -0.2384900003671646, 0.14377999305725098]'
import ast
ast.literal_eval(my_list)
Out[567]: 
[-0.2226099967956543,
 0.2235500067472458,
 -0.2384900003671646,
 0.14377999305725098]
```

Comment: Haha, lucky we both had different solutions :P, i didn't see yours when posting... i was hoping you weren't using `json.loads` :P

Comment: @U9-Forward ah :-) nice solution

Comment: Yeah, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval