# Parse a column of stringified dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  { "name": "foo", "results": "{'lower_bound': '15000', 'upper_bound': '19999'}"},
  { "name": "bar", "results": "{'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}"}
])
```

Currently it looks like this:

```
    name    results
0   foo     {'lower_bound': '15000', 'upper_bound': '19999'}
1   bar     {'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}
```

I'd like to convert the `results` column to structured data, so I can filter for rows where df.lower_bound is less than 13000.

How can I do this?

Comment: Untested but I think you could use from `pandas.io.json import json_normalize` then call the function on your column, explode is another function you can look at as well

Comment: Thanks. The first step might be to convert them from a string field though?

Comment: you were right, thanks! you inadvertently taught me something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another method is using json_normalize and ast_literal

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from ast import literal_eval
```

---

then split out the JSON col and then merge them back on their indices.

```
    s = json_normalize(df['results'].apply(literal_eval).astype(int))
    df_new = pd.merge(df,s,right_index=True,left_index=True)
    print(df_new)
      name  Results                                           lower_bound  upper_bound  
    0  foo  {'lower_bound': '15000', 'upper_bound': '19999'}       15000   19999  
    1  bar  {'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}       10000   14999
```

and for the dtypes  :

```
  print(df_new.dtypes)
    name           object
    results        object
    lower_bound     int32
    upper_bound     int32
    dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be optimum or best way :

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['results'] = df['results'].apply(lambda i: literal_eval(i))
```

This converts the string-formatted values in the `'results'` column to dictionary. Output :

```
  name                                           results
0  foo  {'lower_bound': '15000', 'upper_bound': '19999'}
1  bar  {'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}
```

Then :

```
df['results'] = df['results'].apply(lambda i: {k:int(v) for k,v in i.items()})
```

This converts the values of the dictionaries in that column to integer format from string. Output :

```
  name                                       results
0  foo  {'lower_bound': 15000, 'upper_bound': 19999}
1  bar  {'lower_bound': 10000, 'upper_bound': 14999}
```

Now, get the rows where the dictionary's `lower_bound` key has value < 13000, handle the case even if there is no `lower_bound` key in any row :

```
df.loc[map(lambda i:i.get('lower_bound', '0')<13000, df['results'])]
```

Output :

```
  name                                       results
1  bar  {'lower_bound': 10000, 'upper_bound': 14999}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify your existing DataFrame, you can build a condition by converting "results" into a DataFrame, and then filter:

```
mask = (pd.DataFrame(df['results'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())
          .astype(int)
          .eval('lower_bound < 13000'))
df[mask]

  name                                           results
1  bar  {'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}
```

---

Another option would be to assign this back to the DataFrame via `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([
      df, 
      pd.DataFrame(df.pop('results').apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist()).astype(int)
  ], 
  axis=1)
df[df['lower_bound'] < 13000]

  name lower_bound upper_bound
1  bar       10000       14999
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string expression to a JSON compatible format by replacing the single quotes with double quotes, then convert from JSON to dict:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  { "name": "foo", "results": "{'lower_bound': '15000', 'upper_bound': '19999'}"},
  { "name": "bar", "results": "{'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}"}
])
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.pop('results').apply(lambda x: json.loads(x.replace("'", '"'))).tolist())], axis=1)
```

This is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval) than using `ast.literal_eval` and if you have many rows you will clearly see the difference in execution time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  { "name": "foo", "results": "{'lower_bound': '15000', 'upper_bound': '19999'}"},
  { "name": "bar", "results": "{'lower_bound': '10000', 'upper_bound': '14999'}"}
])
lower_bound = []
upper_bound = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = eval(row['results'])
    lower_bound.append(r['lower_bound'])
    upper_bound.append(r['upper_bound'])
df['lower_bound'] = lower_bound
df['upper_bound'] = upper_bound
print(df[['name', 'lower_bound', 'upper_bound']])
```

result:

```
  name lower_bound upper_bound
0  foo       15000       19999
1  bar       10000       14999
```