# How do I properly convert a string to a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a function that returns a message as a string as follows:

```
 l = ['["sure","kkk"]', '["sure","ii"]']
```

I have tried to remove the `"'"` character through an iteration but its not working for me.
This is my code:

```
print([item.replace('\'["','"').replace('"]\'','"') for item in l])
```

Is there a better way to do this since I want the results as this:

l = [["sure","kkk"], ["sure","ii"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are JSON encoded strings, so you should use the `json` API for that and not try to parse it "yourself":

```
import json

l = ['["sure","kkk"]', '["sure","ii"]']
l = [json.loads(s) for s in l]
print(l)  # [['sure', 'kkk'], ['sure', 'ii']]
```

Can also be achieved with `map` instead of list comprehension:

```
l = list(map(json.loads, l))
```

Comment: I see you eventually changed the acceptance flag to the `literal_eval` answer. If that is what you need, and not JSON parsing, then it would be good to specify more about the use case: do you get your values from system-to-system communication? Do they come from user input? The nice thing about JSON is that it is highly portable and the [`loads` method is significantly faster than `literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223392/why-is-json-loads-an-order-of-magnitude-faster-than-ast-literal-eval).

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have a look at the details. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use `ast.literal_eval` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) as follows:

```py
import ast

l = ['["sure","kkk"]', '["sure","ii"]']
l = [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in l]
print(l)  # [['sure', 'kkk'], ['sure', 'ii']]
```